# Can't figure out why this doesn't work

Tags: jquery

```
$(function () { // document ready
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var top_offset = $('body').offset().top;
        if ((top_offset <= 650)) {

            $('.fluid-width-video-wrapper').addClass('fluid-width-video-wrapper-bottom');

        } else {

         $('.fluid-width-video-wrapper').removeClass('fluid-width-video-wrapper-bottom');

       }

    });
});
```

I literally can't figure out why this doesn't work, this should add a class to .fluid-width-video-wrapper if the page is scrolled more than 650px, or remove the class if it isn't.

Can someone show me my-no-doubt idiotic mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`offset` gives you the top and left pixel offsets of an element relative to the document.

Since the body element is very often starts at the top left corner, it'll give you `top:0` and `left:0` 99% of the time, unless you've done something special to the body tag in CSS.

What you want is `$(window).scrollTop()`

which tells you how far down the page you have scrolled.